# Unity won't switch from Wireframe view in Scene Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

Did some searching around, but I couldn't really find any info on this anywhere. 
In Unity, I switched my scene draw mode from Shader to Wireframe, but now I can't switch back. It keeps throwing nullexceptionerrors that I totally don't understand. I've tried quitting and relaunching, but it doesn't help. Has anyone encountered anything like this before?

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe its a unity bug , can try different version of unity or did you try a new project with the same unity version ?

Comment: Yeah create a unity bug report please. And make sure you add everything they [need](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje5ev5--zuAhWi3OAKHQCqBmcQ9QF6BAgGEAI)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that resetting the UI layout under Layout/Revert Factory Settings will do the trick.